# set_exception_handler ignored in python3.6 with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm basically creating an object that needs to perform a number of tasks in async mode (+ other things but I've tried to simplify here). Here is a snippet of code for the object itself. It's successful (thanks to [Lynn Root's example](https://www.roguelynn.com/words/asyncio-graceful-shutdowns/)) at handling signals - but not at handling exceptions. Or at least not in the way I am hoping to be able to handle them.

```
class myobj(object):
    def __init__(self, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
        self.shutdown = False
        self.loop = loop

    async def graceful_shutdown(self, s=None):
        if s is not None:
            logging.warning(f'Receiving signal {s.name}.')
        else:
            logging.warning(f'Shutting NOT via signal')
        logging.warning(f'Initiating cancellation of {len(self.tasks)} tasks...')
        [task.cancel() for task in self.tasks]
        logging.warning(f'Gaterhing out put of cancellation of {len(self.tasks)} tasks...')
        await asyncio.gather(*self.tasks, loop=self.loop, return_exceptions=True)
        logging.warning('Done graceful shutdown of subtasks')
        # Mark main task to shutdown
        self.shutdown = True

    async def run(self):
        i = 0
        taskx = self.loop.create_task(self.task_x())
        self.tasks = [taskx]
        while not self.shutdown:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print(f'Main runner... {i}')
            i += 1
        logging.warning('Main runner is over.')

    async def task_x(self):
        logging.warning('Starting task X')
        i = 0
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(2.25)
            print(f'Doing task x... {i}')
            if i == 2:
                raise RuntimeError('BOOM X!')
            i += 1
```

At this point, from the "main" I need to install a few things and create the loop :

```
def main():
    try:
        global newobj
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        logging.warning(f'Installing exception handler')
        loop.set_exception_handler(handle_exception)
        logging.warning(f'Creating main object')
        newobj = myobj(loop)
        logging.warning(f'Installing signal handlers')
        signals = (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM)
        for s in signals:
            loop.add_signal_handler(s, lambda s=s: loop.create_task(newobj.graceful_shutdown(s)))
        logging.warning(f'Running object...')
        loop.run_until_complete(newobj.run())
    finally:
        loop.close()
        logging.warning(f'object is Shutdown - Exiting program.')
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But the `handle_exception` needs to be defined.

```
def handle_exception(loop, context):
    # context["message"] will always be there; but context["exception"] may not
    msg = context.get("exception", context["message"])
    logging.error(f'Caught exception: {msg}')
    logging.info(f'Shutting down from exception.')
    loop.create_task(newobj.graceful_shutdown())
```

The problem is that it's never calling `handle_exception`. I need to be running this in python3.6 for some reason. What am I missing here?

Comment: I found that when _not_ using my output of `taskx` (avoiding to do this `self.tasks = [taskx]`), it then runs the exception handler adequately. So it does seem like this exception handler is handling exceptions if they aren't handled otherwise.